# natural 'water' flow through web of nodes

Tags: nodes

Hopefully this will be clear enough.

I have a 2d map made of tiles, and I want "water" to travel through this map.  It comes out of a pipe onto a specific tile, and then needs to fill up, like water, all the tiles to reach a certain other tile.  I currently have the map inputted into the game with each tile being a node and each node having connections to all appropriate tiles around it.  I have the nodes stored in a sorted array, first by x, then by y.  Additionally, some tiles are 'gate' tiles, which can stop water from flowing through them.  These are part of the same grid of node tiles and are just flagged when active.

The problem is how I disperse the water.

Initially I had each pipe (which drops water) keep track of a list of 'current' and 'full' water tiles, and it would disperse water directly to the 'current' tiles, and then switch them to its 'full' list when appropriate.  The 'current' list was expanded by getting surrounding tiles of the already 'current' tiles.  In any case, this worked well, and water flowed nicely, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work with the gates
so that the flow of water could be stopped, and re-allowed, (and stopped again, etc.) at a specific point.

Right now I have it where the water dumps into one and only one tile, and then while a tile has too much water, it pushes the water incrementally onto a random neighboring tiles (unless the tile is an active gate.)  The problem with this is that the water 'sloshes' around already filled tiles instead of flowing 'outward.'  It will get there eventually, but the flow is much less natural.

Thus concludes my dilemma.

The code is written in python.

Edit:
New idea.  I could have the pipe search through the nodes for a suitable free tile to place the water every update, but this seems horribly inefficient--particularly with multiple pipes.

Comment: What SPECIFICALLY are you asking about?

Comment: Specifically, I would like to know how to disperse the water so that it flows outward naturally and can still be inhibited when the gates are up.  If this is not clear enough, I don't know how else to describe it.

Comment: It isn't even remotely clear enough. Are we to understand that you have a square grid of spaces? These gates, they lie at the boundaries of the squares? How "high" are the gates? Are we to understand that you are dispensing integer quantities of liquid, and that each "drop" can only lie in a single square at a time? Does it bother you that this is non-physical (and if not, why)? How realistic do you want this simulation to be, and how fast a flow must it accommodate? You're going to have to *specify* the problem, what you have done, how it is performing, and how you *want* it to perform...

Comment: A picture says a thousand words... http://i346.photobucket.com/albums/p402/natchela/waterflow.png

For what's not visible, yes, I am dispensing integer quantities of liquid, and each "drop" can only lie in one square.  As for realism, I would like the flow to be consistent.  To elaborate, if I slowly poor water onto the floor, it pools, and the new water pushes the old water outward (for a simplistic view.)  What happens with my current code, is that it pools, and the rate of the outward spread of water is variable to the randomness that comes with how it's currently moving between tiles.

Comment: Allowing only integer depths is going to make you life very difficult.

Comment: What would you propose instead?

Comment: Real liquids spread out in continuous fashion, which has the advantage of making the interaction locally computable. You can use floats, or allow depths that represent a small fraction of the volume of a drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes up a lot in game development -- there have been many GDC talks and Gamasutra/Game Developer magazine feature articles on this very subject. The best for your purposes I think is [Jos Stam](https://www.dgp.toronto.edu/%7Estam/reality/Research/pub.html)'s "[Real-Time Fluid Dynamics for Games](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAcQFjAA&url=http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/stam/reality/Research/pdf/GDC03.pdf&ei=DqE1S4DUCIffnAfN2qX1CA&usg=AFQjCNEcsNAukYsrtzmEwYFIfPM0YiawOg&sig2=h0MvgVqF0d7qkkdMsOln2A)" from the 2003 GDC.

He describes a simplified way of performing *advection* via a *linear backtrace* which suffers from some problems but works quite well for incompressible fluids (that is to say, it works better for water than for gas). Linear backtrace means basically that he sets up a grid representing fluid density at each point in space (that's your tiles), and then for each frame visits each point and asks, "based on the pressure at the surrounding points, where is the fluid likely to *come from*?" This turns out to be easier than solving it the other way ("where is the fluid from this point going to go?").

[Mick West's article on fluid dynamics](https://www.gamedeveloper.com/legacy/view/feature/1549/practical_fluid_dynamics_part_1.php) for Gamasutra extends Stam's paper in some ways that may improve performance, so you may want to start there.

There is also [a recent Intel-sponsored GameDev article that offers a more complete solution](https://www.gamedeveloper.com/legacy/view/feature/4164/sponsored_feature_fluid_.php), but it's rather complicated and focused more on the graphical rendering side in 3d.

You can look at *Dwarf Fortress* for an example of tiled 2d fluid mechanics, but his solution seems to have a bunch of problems dealing with fast-flowing or pressurized fluids; sometimes his water moves way more sluggishly than you'd expect, or gets caught up in blocks and corners.

Those papers summarize the math and algorithm way better than I could cram into a Stack Overflow box, but there's two general points I'd like to make too:

1. Water simulation is very computationally expensive. Since you're working in Python, this may result in a real performance problem -- be sure to set up some means of profiling your algorithm to find the hotspots in case your loop takes so long that it kills framerate. You may have to resort to [Numeric Python](https://numpy.org/) to get fast C-based array operations.
2. There is way more math in game development than most people expect!

Comment: Thank you for the links--I found them interesting, particularly since my background is math, not programming.

However, I decided they were way too complicated for what I want from this game, and took the idea "where is the fluid likely to come from?" altering my previous code so that the cells 'pull' water instead of 'push' it.  Turns out, for the dispersion to be as on a flat floor, not slanted with update order, this ended up creating wells by drop points making the expansion slow down too much as the pools increased in size.  An adjustment, growing only when 'on,' fixed this.  Thank you.

Comment: Absolutely sensible -- it's always best to use the simplest solution that could possibly work. Especially if the specific discrete placement of water in tiles is the core of the game, you want it to be something simple and predictable (by the player) and abstract.

Answer (score 2):

Some heuristics on the assumptions:

- discrete "drops" which occupy exactly one square each
- the water never remains more than one high on a given tile,
- the water always remains continuous
- when the barriers are up they are like walls
- when the barriers are down they are like open squares

For every puddle, maintain a list of edge squares and open squares next to the edges.

When a barrier goes down

```
amend the lists of edge and open squares for any puddles that were touching it
```

When a barrier goes up

```
if (it was covered)
    pick a non-wall square next to it at random, and add the drop from the barrier there.
amend the lists of edge and open squares for any puddles next to the block
```

When you add a drop:

```
if (the square "under" the pipe is empty)
   fill it
else
   consult the list of edge square associated with the pool under the pipe, and select the one closest to the pipe (if more than one is closest, choose from the candidates at random), and fill it.  
amend the lists of edge and open squares for the puddle (be prepared to merge with neighboring puddles if necessary)
```

When you remove a drop

```
 find the edge (not open!) square farthest from the sink (or randomly select from the equivalent candidates), and empty it
 amend the lists of edge and open squares for the puddle
```

(a frill available here is to make the "farthest" bounded by equal distance to other sinks, so that squares in the middle of a puddle can become empty if they are between sinks)

This isn't very realistic, and doesn't get you any dynamics to speak of, but will maintain continuous puddles "under" the dripping pipes and fill up the available space given enough drips.

Comment: This seems like an extension of the first idea I tried, only it amends/truncates the lists as needed depending on the status of the gates (at least that's what I gather.)  I hadn't thought of doing it this way, though I decided not to go with it due to the searching and needing to know which edge tiles would be reachable, in their most direct route, though the gate, as well as other maintenance issues for the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Does your model include a concept of potential difference or pressure?

Say an empty tile has zero pressure, a full tile a pressure of 10. If theres a pipe between two tiles then water flows to equalise the pressure, a gate closes a pipe so nothing flows.

Comment: No. Right now, the tiles are considered 'full' when they hold 2 water.  I'm afraid I wasn't clear in describing the situation, and there are not pipes between the tiles--they should act as a kitchen floor.  However, I can see that if I mimicked that behavior, the 'sloshing' would stop.

Comment: more generally, I think the OP needs to do a little reading bout how water moves and flows. He won't need a full fluid dynamic model, but I you want the behavior to look natural, you're going to need a model with some physics built into the heuristics.